# Fade a background image down on hover to reveal the background color?

Tags: jquery, css

Is it possible, on hover, to fade the background image opacity down to reveal more of the background color?

Essentially, I want the background color to be black, so when the image is hovered, it looks like it's getting darker.

This is how it's set up:

```
<a href="#" class="new-cinema" style="background-image:url('images/promo-1.jpg');">
    <span class="main-title">New<br />Cinema<br />Openings</span>
</a>
```

By using something like the following, it just fades the image:

```
opacity: 0.75;
transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
```

Comment: Have you attempted any jQuery to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do by adding a physical image to the DOM and reducing the opacity of the image on hover. You don't need a jQuery, but a pure CSS solution is here:

```css
a {position: relative; overflow: hidden; background: #000; display: inline-block;}
a img {position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;}
a img, a:hover img {transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out; -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out; -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;}
a:hover img {opacity: 0.5;}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="new-cinema">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" />
  <span class="main-title">New<br />Cinema<br />Openings</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a pseudo-element and leave the styling in the CSS rather than having an image in the HTML.

```css
.new-cinema {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 25px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  text-align: center;
  background: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
  padding: .5em;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.new-cinema:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports/);
  background: cover;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}
.new-cinema:hover:after {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.main-title {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="new-cinema">
  <span class="main-title">New<br />Cinema<br />Openings</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it with a inset `box-shadow`. If this is a performance issue someone please correct me.

```
a {
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 100px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  transition: box-shadow .25s ease-in-out;
}
   a:hover {
     box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 100px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
   }
```

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q5osfcg2/